# Não consigo formatar data

Tags: java, data, formatação, simpledateformat

Estou tentando formatar uma data para ficar igual a outra, a primeira vem direto do banco mas a outra precisa estar no mesmo formato.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String d = df.format(cal.getTime());

Date antigo = rs.getDate("datapi");
DiasUteis du = new DiasUteis();

Date data = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(d);

System.out.println(antigo + " - " + data);
```

O resultado é o seguinte:

> 2017-10-03 - Mon Jul 02 00:00:00 BRT 2018

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Supondo que `rs` é um [`java.sql.ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)</sup>

---

Primeiro, uma explicação do que acontece.

O método [`rs.getDate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate-java.lang.String-) retorna um [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), e o código só funciona porque esta é uma subclasse de [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). Mas o objeto que está lá na variável `antigo` é um `java.sql.Date`.

Já o método [`SimpleDateFormat.parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-) retorna um `java.util.Date`.

Quando você imprime ambas com `System.out.println`, internamente ele chama o método `toString()` destas classes. E em cada uma delas este método retorna a data em um formato diferente:

- em `java.sql.Date`, é usado o formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (`2017-10-03`)
- em `java.util.Date`, é usado esse outro formato (que não lembro se tem um nome específico): `Mon Jul 02 00:00:00 BRT 2018`

Mas isso não quer dizer que a data **está** nesse formato. Na verdade, conforme já dito [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/364683/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/368075/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/367704/112052), **datas não têm formato**.

Provavelmente o campo no banco de dados é de algum tipo de data (como `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP`, etc, depende do banco), e internamente só são gravados valores (geralmente os valores numéricos da data, ou qualquer outra representação interna, não importa).

O que o método `toString()` faz é converter estes valores para um texto (uma `String`) em algum formato específico, mas isso não quer dizer que a data **está** nesse formato.

Se eu quero uma data (**valores** numéricos do dia, mês, ano, etc), eu uso os respectivos objetos (`Date`, `Calendar`, etc).

Se eu quero os valores da data em um formato específico, eu gero uma `String` usando classes específicas para este fim, como por exemplo `SimpleDateFormat`.

---

Agora vamos ao seu código:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String d = df.format(cal.getTime());
```

Aqui você criou uma `String` (a variável `d`), que contém a data atual (retornada por [`Calendar.getInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance--)), no formato "ano-mês-dia". Por que você simplesmente não imprimiu esta data, já que ela está no formato que você precisa? (a menos que não seja esta a data que você quer imprimir).

---

```
Date antigo = rs.getDate("datapi");
```

Aqui você está obtendo o `java.sql.Date`. Se você quer esta data no formato correto, basta chamar `antigo.toString()`, que retorna uma `String` no formato "ano-mês-dia".

---

```
Date data = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(d);
```

E aqui você está transformando a `String` `d` em um `java.util.Date`. Isso é desnecessário, pois o `d` já contém uma `String` com a data no formato que você quer (e mesmo que fosse necessário, você poderia usar a variável `df` criada anteriormente, ao invés de criar outro `SimpleDateFormat`).

Enfim, se você tem um objeto `Date` e quer gerar uma `String` em um formato específico, use `SimpleDateFormat` e o método `format`, passando o `Date` como parâmetro.

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String d = df.format(cal.getTime());

Date antigo = rs.getDate("datapi");
DiasUteis du = new DiasUteis();

Date data = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(d);

System.out.println(antigo + " - " + df.format(data));
```

Você poderia testar o código acima e comentar qual foi o resultado?