# Formatar LocalDate e passar como Parâmetro

Tags: java, data, conversão-de-tipo, formatação

Tenho este método:

```
private void tratarIFMandato(String [] d) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    LocalDate dt1 = LocalDate.parse(d[0].trim(), formatter);
    System.out.println(dt1);
}
```

Que está recebendo uma data no formato `"dd/MM/yyyy"` e retorna `1990-03-15`.

Preciso passar a `String` para um `LocalDate` pois tenho um método `set` que vai receber um `LocalDate` como parâmetro e um `get` que vai me retornar um `LocalDate`.

A soluçao que encontrei foi de fazer meu método `get` retornar um `DateTimeFormatter` e dar um `return formatter.format(dt1);` dentro do meu `get`, porem **preciso** que seja retornado um `LocalDate` no formato `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Como faço para retornar a data no formato `dd/MM/yyyy`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você "*retornar a data no formato `dd/MM/yyyy`*", ela deixa de ser uma data (um `LocalDate`) e vira uma `String`. Para entender melhor, segue abaixo uma - longa - explicação.

## Datas não têm formato

Uma data é apenas um conceito, uma ideia: ela representa um ponto específico no calendário.

A data de "15 de março de 1990" representa isso: o ponto específico do calendário, ocorrido há vários anos atrás, que convencionamos chamar de dia 15 do mês de março do ano de 1990. Para expressar essa ideia em forma de texto, eu posso escrevê-la de diferentes formas:

- 15/03/1990 (um formato bem comum em muitos países, incluindo o Brasil)
- 3/15/1990 (formato americano, invertendo o dia e mês)
- 1990-03-15 (o formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601))
- 15 de março de 1990 (em bom português)
- March 15<sup>th</sup>, 1990 (em inglês)
- 1990年3月15日 (em japonês)
- e muitos outros...

Repare que cada um dos formatos acima é diferente, mas **todos representam a mesma data** (os mesmos valores numéricos do dia, mês e ano).

---

De maneira similar, em Java temos a classe [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), que implementa o conceito de uma data (um dia, mês e ano específicos), e temos a classe `String`, que pode conter um texto que representa uma data (qualquer um dos formatos acima, e qualquer outro que você quiser).

Um `LocalDate`, por si só, não possui nenhum formato específico. Internamente, esta classe possui [apenas 3 valores numéricos](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/43cb25339b55/src/share/classes/java/time/LocalDate.java#l166): o dia, mês e ano.

Quando você imprime um `LocalDate` (seja com `System.out.println`, com uma API de log, ou até mesmo vendo seu valor em um *debugger*), internamente é chamado o método [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--), que retorna os valores do dia, mês e ano formatados em uma `String`. No caso da API `java.time`, optou-se por retornar esta `String` no [formato ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (por isso a data é mostrada como `1990-03-15`).

Ou seja, ao fazer `System.out.println(dt1)`, você vê o retorno do método `toString()`, que retorna os valores da data em um formato específico (em uma `String`). Mas isso não quer dizer que o `LocalDate` **está** naquele formato. Na verdade, ele não está em formato nenhum, pois ele sequer possui um.

Apenas para exemplificar:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
LocalDate dt1 = LocalDate.parse("15/03/1990", formatter);
System.out.println(dt1); // 1990-03-15

LocalDate dt2 = LocalDate.of(1990, 3, 15);
System.out.println(dt2); // 1990-03-15

System.out.println(dt1.equals(dt2)); // true
```

A primeira data (`dt1`) foi criada a partir de uma `String`. Como esta `String` representa uma data no formato "dia/mês/ano", eu usei o `DateTimeFormatter` com esse formato e fiz o `parse` para obter o `LocalDate`. Então agora `dt1` corresponde a "15 de março de 1990".

Mas internamente `dt1` não possui nenhum formato. Ela possui somente os valores numéricos (dia 15, mês 3 e ano 1990). `dt1` não sabe que esses valores vieram de uma `String` (quem fez essa correspondência entre o que estava na `String` e os valores numéricos foi o `DateTimeFormatter`).

É claro que, ao imprimir `dt1`, ela tem que ser mostrada de algum jeito, e o seu método `toString()` acaba mostrando no [formato ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Mas isso não quer dizer que `dt1` está naquele formato.

Já `dt2` foi criada usando-se os valores numéricos diretamente. Ela também só possui os valores, e não tem nenhuma informação quanto ao formato. Tanto que `dt1` e `dt2` são iguais (correspondem à mesma data - ao mesmo ponto do calendário - os seus valores numéricos do dia, mês e ano são iguais): veja na última linha que `dt1.equals(dt2)` imprime `true`.

---

Sendo assim, você deve decidir o que precisa em cada ponto do código.

Se o método `setInicioMandato` recebe um `LocalDate` como parâmetro, basta passá-lo diretamente, sem se preocupar com o formato (até porque o `LocalDate` não tem nenhum formato, somente os valores numéricos do dia, mês e ano).

Se você quer mostrar a data em algum formato diferente, aí é o caso de convertê-la para `String`, usando um `DateTimeFormatter`.

---

#### Bônus

Apenas para complementar, veja o que acontece se a `String` tiver datas como 31 de abril ou 29 de fevereiro em anos não bissextos:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
LocalDate dt1 = LocalDate.parse("31/04/2019", formatter);
System.out.println(dt1); // 2019-04-30
LocalDate dt2 = LocalDate.parse("29/02/2019", formatter);
System.out.println(dt2); // 2019-02-28
```

31 de abril é inválido, pois abril só tem 30 dias. Mas `31/04/2019` foi aceito e **ajustado** para 30 de abril. Já `29/02/2019` (que também é inválido, pois 2019 não é ano bissexto) foi ajustado para 28 de fevereiro.

Se quiser evitar essas situações e aceitar somente datas válidas, basta mudar o [`java.time.format.ResolverStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html), usando o valor [`STRICT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#STRICT) (conforme sugerido [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187296/112052)). Com isso, datas inválidas lançam uma exceção:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu")
    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
LocalDate dt1 = LocalDate.parse("31/04/2019", formatter);
```

O código acima tenta fazer o *parsing* de uma data inválida, mas devido ao `ResolverStyle.STRICT`, ele lança uma exceção:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '31/04/2019' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {YearOfEra=2019, MonthOfYear=4, DayOfMonth=31},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed

Outro detalhe - que você já deve ter percebido - é usar `uuuu` para o ano, em vez de `yyyy`. De maneira bem resumida, `u` funciona tanto para anos atuais quanto para datas A.C. (Antes de Cristo), aceitando anos negativos, enquanto `y` precisa da era (A.C. ou B.C.) para decidir se ano é Antes ou Depois de Cristo (no *parsing* não vemos esses problemas porque a era é inferida e para datas atuais funciona normalmente).

Talvez o uso de datas tão antigas não seja tão comum em muitas aplicações, mas de qualquer forma, o uso de `u` em vez de `y` é recomendado. Para mais detalhes, veja [esta pergunta no Stack Overflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41177442).

Answer (score 0):

O seu código está errado porque ao utilizar o Parse do LocalDate, por padrão o retorno vai ser no formato iso (yyyy-MM-dd).

A mascara que vc utiliza no método parse é a máscara que está na variável que vc informou no método.

Primeiro vc realizar o parse, realiza as operações necessárias com a data se valendo dos métodos da Classe LocalDate, só então, se for necessário vc utiliza o DateTimeFormatter para mudar o formato para o que vc desejar....

```
LocalDate dt1 = LocalDate.parse("suastringaqui", o formato de sua string aqui);

LocalDate dt1 = LocalDate.parse("15/08/2020", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

System.out.println(dt1.format(formatter));
```

Veja o resultado aqui: https://ideone.com/pWMdrL