# Data com PHP + SQL fazer operações

Tags: php, mysql, data, timestamp

Eu tenho algumas dúvidas: eu preciso guardar duas datas na mesma tabela do banco de dados, e vou precisar fazer uma função para comparar as datas depois.

Na verdade eu já tenho um teste disso pronto, porém achei que fiz conversão demais, não sei se é o certo, sei que deu certo, mas como estamos em aprendizado constante gostaria de saber a opinião de vocês sobre a função e se é possível melhorar.

Levando em consideração que vou usar as datas para fazer contas entre elas:

1. Melhor tipo de dados para salvar (timestamp, data, datetime)
2. Atualmente eu estou salvando assim: `dat timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, porém o formato da data fica pré-formatado ex: `2019-03-11 11:08:39`, o certo não seria ficar em um valor inteiro?

Meu código:

```
$dataprincipal = strtotime(date('d/m/Y H:i:s'));
$datadelete = strtotime(date('d/m/Y H:i:s').'+30 min');

$comparador1 = strtotime(date('d/m/Y H:i:s',$dataprincipal).'+30 min');
$comparador2 = strtotime(date('d/m/Y H:i:s',$datadelete).'+0 min');

if($comparador1 == $comparador2)
{
    echo $comparador1;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $comparador2;
    echo '<br><br><br>data 1 '.date('d/m/Y H:i:s',$dataprincipal.'+0 min');
    echo '<br>data 2 '.date('d/m/Y H:i:s',$dataprincipal);
} else {
    echo 'as datas são diferentes';
}
```

A ideia principal é pegar as duas datas e comparar, se as duas datas forem iguais vou deletar a linha do banco de dados, porém preciso fazer isso no PHP porque **preciso deletar um arquivo X dependendo da comparação e das somas entre as datas**.

Esse foi só um exemplo, **minha preocupação maior é saber qual é o melhor formato para se tratar uma data quando eu vou usar elas para fazer operações matemáticas**. Por exemplo, quando eu vou salvar um **CPF** eu uso `char` e não `int`, porque normalmente não se faz operações com CPF então entendo que ele seria uma string, nesse caso qual a melhor forma?

Answer (score 1):

Conforme eu já disse em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/364683/112052):

## Datas não têm formato

Datas e horas são apenas conceitos, ideias: uma data representa um ponto específico no calendário, um horário representa um momento específico de um dia.

A data/hora de "11 de março de 2019 às 11:08:39" representa duas ideias:

- a data representa ponto específico do calendário, o dia 11 do mês de março do ano de 2019.
- o horário representa um ponto específico deste dia: 11 horas (da manhã), 8 minutos e 39 segundos.

Para expressar essas ideias em forma de texto, eu posso escrevê-las de diferentes formas:

- 11/03/2019 11:08:39 (um formato bem comum em muitos países, incluindo o Brasil)
- 3/15/1990 11:08:39 AM (formato americano, invertendo o dia e mês e usando AM para as horas)
- 2019-03-11T11:08:39 (o formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601))
- 11 de março de 2019, 11h08 (em bom português)
- March 11<sup>th</sup>, 2019, 11:08 AM (em inglês)
- 2019年3月11日 11時08分39秒 (em japonês)
- e muitos outros...

Repare que cada um dos formatos acima é diferente, mas **todos representam a mesma data e hora** (os mesmos valores numéricos do dia, mês, ano, hora, minuto e segundo).

Quando você salva uma data e hora no banco de dados, usando os tipos disponíveis (seja `timestamp`, ou `datetime`, ou `date`, ou o que for), o banco guarda esses valores e pronto. O formato em que essas informações estão lá é detalhe de implementação interna e não importa.

Quando você faz um `SELECT` no banco, ou mostra esses valores na tela com `echo`, ou grava em um arquivo de log, ou o que for, obviamente esses valores serão mostrados em algum formato. Mas isso não quer dizer que a data/hora **está** necessariamente naquele formato.

---

### Qual tipo usar? Depende

De acordo com a [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) do MySQL referente aos tipos de data/hora, temos:

- `DATE`: guarda apenas o dia, mês e ano. Se você **não** precisa dos horários, é uma boa escolha (por exemplo, para guardar apenas a data de nascimento de usuários em um cadastro simples - mas se for um sistema de hospital ou cartório, por exemplo, ou qualquer outro contexto que precise do horário, aí já não é indicado usá-lo).
- `DATETIME` e `TIMESTAMP`: ambos possuem a data e hora. A diferença é que `TIMESTAMP` converte a data/hora do timezone atual (o usado na conexão) para UTC quando a data é gravada, e converte de volta (de UTC para o timezone atual) ao consultar os dados (veja a [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html) para mais detalhes - eu particularmente acho essas conversões bem confusas).

Não conheço a fundo as funções `mysqli_xxx`, mas pelo que me lembro, mesmo datas são retornadas como strings (por isso você tem a impressão de que as datas estão em determinado formato). Mas lembre-se que isso é apenas uma representação dos valores guardados no banco.

Mas um `DATETIME` ainda pode ser ambíguo, dependendo do que você precisa. Por exemplo, "11 de março de 2019 às 11 da manhã" ocorreu em um instante diferente em cada parte do mundo (na Austrália essa data e hora ocorreu várias horas antes do Brasil, por exemplo). Se você quiser saber exatamente em que instante determinado evento ocorreu, o melhor é usar um timestamp (não o tipo do MySQL, mas sim o [valor numérico que representa a quantidade de segundos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052) decorridos deste o [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)).

No MySQL podemos usar `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` para obter este valor:

```
mysql> select unix_timestamp();
+------------------+
| unix_timestamp() |
+------------------+
|       1552350656 |
+------------------+
```

O valor retornado é a quantidade de segundos desde o [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) e pode ser guardado em um campo numérico. A vantagem de ser um número é poder ser facilmente comparado com outros (quanto maior o valor, mais no futuro está o timestamp).

O detalhe é que esse valor (1552350656) representa um único instante (um ponto na linha do tempo), que é o mesmo no mundo todo. Mas em cada fuso horário ele pode corresponder a uma data e hora diferente. O valor acima, por exemplo, corresponde a [11/03/2019 às 21:30 em São Paulo](https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1552350656&tz=America%2FSao_Paulo#convert-tz), mas a [12/03/2019 às 09:30 em Tóquio](https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1552350656&tz=Asia%2FTokyo#convert-tz). Se for mostrá-lo na tela, lembre-se de converter para o timezone correto. Exemplo:

```
// criar data a partir do timestamp
$data = new DateTime('@'. 1552350656);
// converter para um timezone
$data->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
// mostrar em algum formato
echo $data->format('d/m/Y H:i:s'); // 11/03/2019 21:30:56
```

Para o caso de receber uma string, use [`createFromFormat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$data = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2019-03-11 11:08:39');
```

Neste caso, como não setei o timezone, a data já terá os valores indicados na string (usando o timezone *default* [que estiver configurado no PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)).

Ao manipular as datas como instâncias de `DateTime`, é possível compará-las e calcular a diferença entre as mesmas:

```
$data2 = new DateTime();
if($data < $data2) {
    var_dump($data2->diff($data));
}
```

O método `diff` retorna um [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), que possui informações detalhadas sobre a diferença entre as datas (quantos anos, meses, dias, horas, minutos e segundos há entre elas, em campos separados).

Para somar/subtrair durações a uma data, pode usar os métodos [`add`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) e [`sub`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php). Ambos recebem um `DateInterval` como parâmetro:

```
$data = new DateTime('@'. 1552350656);
// somar 30 minutos, usando o formato ISO 8601 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations)
$data->add(new DateInterval('PT30M'));

// ou usando os formatos relativos (https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)
$data->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('30 minutes'));
```

Você pode usar tanto o formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) (`PT30M` equivale a uma duração de 30 minutos), quanto os [formatos relativos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) (como "30 minutes").

---

#### Resumindo

Trabalhar com datas é um assunto amplo, mas de forma geral o PHP já possui tipos específicos com várias funcionalidades para comparar, calcular diferença, formatar, etc. A mesma coisa vale para o banco de dados.

Se o seu código está recebendo strings, converta-as para datas e faça as devidas manipulações (comparações, aritmética de datas, etc) usando os tipos específicos (`DateTime`, por exemplo). Só converta as datas para strings (convertendo-as para um formato específico) quando necessário (seja para mostrar para o usuário, gravar em um arquivo de log, ou para qualquer operação que exija uma string).