# Como posso gravar um input HTML DateTime-Local no banco de dados com o Campo do tipo DateTime?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, datetime, datetime-local

No projeto que estou desenvolvendo em PHP necessito de um  em um formulário de cadastro. Eu queria saber como eu posso fazer para salvar este dado no banco, tentei utilizar o tipo DateTime no MYSQL, mas este tipo conta com o layout de horas:minutos:segundos já o  utiliza o tipo horas:minutos. 
Se alguém conseguir esclarecer, agradeço e muito. 
Eu realmente preciso que o banco tenha um dado com a data e o dia juntos, e não separados, como seria o correto a se fazer.

Comment: O datetime do MySQL guarda a data e hora, e [**datas não têm formato**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/367704/112052). Se vc faz um select, o banco pode até mostrar no formato "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" ou em qualquer outro, mas isso não quer dizer que a data **está** naquele formato. O banco só guarda os valores da data/hora e é com isso que vc deve se preocupar. O formato não faz parte da data em si. Se quer mostrar a data em um formato específico, faça a conversão no PHP

Comment: Acabei de fazer a conversão, foi bem mais fácil que eu esperava, pensei nessa função voltando para casa de ônibus, apenas precisei ver como o Datetime-local passava o valor, Data normal: 2019-04-05T12:12 ai é só usar o str_replace pra tirar esse T e colocar um espaço, e colocar o ":00" no final com concatenaçao, assim eu consigo gravar no banco tranquilamente. O meu projeto demanda muito pouco tempo e eu não queria colocar a mãos no JQuery e JS do calendário, só precisava desse Datetime do MYSQL por causa deste calendario.