# A conversão de data sempre se mantém em pt-BR?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data

Estou tentando converter uma data no Asp.Net MVC para `yyyy-MM-dd`, o que acontece é que sempre quando converto e exibo essa data ela fica `dd/MM/yyyy` e não sei porque isso acontece.

Como resolver isso?

```
String d1 = `2019-03-01`;
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(d1);
Debug.Writeline(d);

Resultado: saida 01/03/2019
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Isso acontece porque você não está formatando a saída. [**Datas não têm formato**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/368075/18246), o que é formatado é representação desta data em string.

É possível definir o formato da string representando uma data usando o método `.ToString()`

```
Debug.Writeline(d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Neste caso, a cultura não vai fazer nenhuma diferença, então omiti a mesma. De forma geral é sempre bom usá-la, até por questões de costume e/ou manutenção de código (caso alguém troque o formato, por exemplo).

Comment: +1 por ser a única resposta - além da minha :-) - a ressaltar que datas não têm formato (algo que **muita** gente se confunde ao manipular datas)

Answer (score 14):

<sup>Conforme eu já disse [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/364683/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/367704/112052):</sup>

## Datas não têm formato

Uma data é apenas um conceito, uma ideia: ela representa um ponto específico no calendário.

A data de "1 de março de 2019" representa isso: o ponto específico do calendário, que corresponde ao dia 1 do mês de março do ano de 2019. Para expressar essa ideia em forma de texto, eu posso escrevê-la de diferentes formas:

- 01/03/2019 (um formato bem comum em muitos países, incluindo o Brasil)
- 3/1/2019 (formato americano, invertendo o dia e mês)
- 2019-03-01 (o formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601))
- primeiro de março de 2019 (em bom português)
- March 1<sup>st</sup>, 2019 (em inglês)
- 2019年3月1日 (em japonês)
- e muitos outros...

Repare que cada um dos formatos acima é diferente, mas **todos representam a mesma data** (os mesmos valores numéricos do dia, mês e ano).

---

Dito isso, a string `2019-03-01` é apenas um texto que representa a data em um formato específico. Quando você transforma esta string em um `DateTime`, está criando um objeto que contém os respectivos **valores** (dia 1, mês 3, ano 2019). Mas a data em si não está em um formato específico.

Quando você imprime a data, claro, ela tem que ser mostrada em algum formato. Métodos como `WriteLine`, ao receber um `DateTime`, usam por padrão um formato predefinido conforme o [`CurrentCulture`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Globalization_CultureInfo_CurrentCulture) (veja a explicação detalhada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32374801)).

Se quer usar um formato específico sem depender do `CurrentCulture` (ou sem precisar mudá-lo), use [`ToString(formato)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_). Exemplo:

```
d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") // retorna 2019-03-01
```

Lembrando que este método retorna uma string: uma representação da data em um formato específico, não a data (o `DateTime`) em si.

Comment: Ótima resposta! Eu ia melhorar a minha, mas esta aqui está perfeita.

Answer (score 6):

**Tente fazer:**

```
string d1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

**Ou então se for o caso:**

```
d1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode deixar explícito o formato da data que quer na saída usando o ParseExact():

> public static DateTime ParseExact (string s, string format, IFormatProvider provider);

Mais informações:

[DateTime.ParseExact Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```js
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
string d1 = "2019-03-01";
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd";

DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(d1, format, culture);
```

Comment: Eu já havia tentado o `DateTime.ParseExact` mas continua sempre exibindo `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: Sua resposta está errada. O AP procura outra coisa.

Comment: É porque você está procurando apenas o formato de exibição da data na saida e não na entrada. Creio que as respostas que já deram então vao te atender!