# Mudar formato de uma data de "yyyy-mm-dd" para "dd/mm/yyyy"

Tags: php, string, datetime, data

Estou tentando mudar o formato de uma data de `yyyy-mm-dd` para `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Estou usando este código:

```
$date = "2019-03-27";
$date1 = new DateTime(date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', $date)->format('d/m/Y'));

echo $date1;
```

Mas dá esse erro:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (27/03/2019) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character in [...][...]:4
Stack trace:
#0 [...][...](4): DateTime-&gt;__construct('27/03/2019')
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Resposta curta

```
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', "2019-03-27");
echo $date1->format('d/m/Y');
```

Saída:

> 27/03/2019

---

## Resposta longa

<sup>Conforme já dito [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/364683/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/368075/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/367704/112052):</sup>

### Datas não têm formato

Uma data é apenas um conceito, uma ideia: ela representa um ponto específico no calendário.

A data de "27 de março de 2019" representa isso: o ponto específico do calendário que corresponde ao dia 27 do mês de março do ano de 2019.
Para expressar essa ideia em forma de texto, eu posso escrevê-la de diferentes formas:

- 27/03/2019 (um formato bem comum em muitos países, incluindo o Brasil)
- 3/27/2019 (formato americano, invertendo o dia e mês)
- 2019-03-27 (o formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601))
- 27 de Março de 2019 (em bom português)
- March 27<sup>th</sup>, 2019 (em inglês)
- 2019年3月27日 (em japonês)
- e muitos outros...

Repare que cada um dos formatos acima é diferente, mas **todos representam a mesma data** (os mesmos valores numéricos do dia, mês e ano).

Dito isso, a **string** `2019-03-27` não é uma data, e sim uma das muitas maneiras possíveis de se representar uma.

Já um `DateTime` é um objeto que representa *a ideia* (o conceito) de uma data, e ele por si só não tem um formato.

Então o que você deve fazer é:

- converter a string `2019-03-27` para um `DateTime`
- converter este `DateTime` em outra string, com o formato desejado

O primeiro passo é feito com [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), que recebe como parâmetro o formato e a respectiva string.

O segundo passo é feito com o método [`format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), que converte o `DateTime` para uma string, usando algum formato específico.

---

No seu código você está usando `format` antes da hora, e acaba passando a string `27/03/2019` para o construtor de `DateTime`. Mas [segundo a documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php), quando uma string assim é passada (usando barras como separadores), ela é interpretada no formato americano (mês/dia/ano). E como "27" não é um mês válido, dá o erro.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer dessa maneira

```
   $date = "2019-03-27";
   $date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 1):

> [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php) — Interpreta qualquer descrição de data/hora [...] em timestamp Unix

O `strtotime` transforma qualquer string em um inteiro (o timestamp unix).

A Função [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php) formata um tempo retornando uma string

```
$date = strtotime("2019-03-27");
// $data agora é uma inteiro timestamp
$dateformated = date("d/m/Y", $date);
// date() formatou o $date para d/m/Y
echo($dateformated);
// Saida: 27/03/2019
```