# Como tratar diferentes formatos de data?

Tags: java, android, regex, data, simpledateformat

Tenho uma aplicação que em determinado momento recupero a data obtida do sistema, guardo em uma tabela no banco de dados (SQLite) e depois a recupero.

O problema é que em determinador dispositivos tenho a data padrão `dd/MM/yyyy` (01/01/1970) e em outros `dd 'de' MMM 'de' yyyy` (01 de jan de 1970).

Como solução vejo a saída da data para depois usar umas dessas linhas:

```
SimpleDateFormat motorola = new SimpleDateFormat("dd 'de' MMM 'de' yyyy"); // compila para MOTOROLA
SimpleDateFormat samsung = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); //compila para Samsung
```

Há um meio de utilizar o regex para simplificar as coisas?
Seria ótimo obter a universalidade do código, independente do dispositivo utilizado.

Teria como comparar essa data recebida diretamente no `SimpleDateFormat`?

```
String DatePattern = "^(?:(31)(\D)(0?[13578]|1[02])\2|(29|30)(\D)(0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\5|(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\D)(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\8)((?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(29)(\D)(0?2)\12((?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)$";
```

Como eu obteria um padrão para essas datas?

Por exemplo, a saída sempre será `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Comment: Como está a obter a data do sistema? O que pretende é ter uma string que represente essa data sempre no mesmo formato, independentemente do dispositivo/configuração do usuário?

Comment: Exatamente @ramaral, obtenho a data e transformo em uma String, gravo no banco e recupero essa String depois, e como sugerido nas resposta abaixo já utilizo os imports necessários para minha aplicação 'enxergar' de onde quero essa data:
      import java.util.Calendar;
      import java.util.Date;
      import java.util.Locale;
     

        Calendar myCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        myCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5); // adiciona 5 dias na data
        final String cts = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(myCal.getTime()); talvez aqui eu esteja passando os argumentos errados

Comment: Basicamente obtenho uma data inicial DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
e transformo para obter o que chamo de "devolução" Calendar.getInstance(); myCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5);

Comment: `getDateInstance()` usa o formato baseado no locale default e isso varia de um ambiente pro outro. Se quer usar sempre o mesmo formato, use `SimpleDateFormat` com um formato específico, como já sugerido abaixo. Dê uma lida também em http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-date/

Comment: De qualquer forma, atualizei [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/379528/112052) com pequeno teste feito no SQLite (não uso ele com muita frequência, então posso não ter feito da melhor maneira, mas a ideia geral não muda muito, então acredito que vai ajudá-lo) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obter uma string no formato desejado, independentemente do dispositivo/configurações do usuário, faça assim:

```
//Obtenha um Calendar com a data actual
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

// manipule a data como pretender,
// por exemplo, adicionar 5 dias
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5)

//Construa um DateFormat, com o o formato pretendido
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

// Obtenha a String que representa a data nesse formato
String formattedDate = df.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 5):

<sup>Conforme eu já disse [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/364683/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/368075/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/367704/112052):</sup>

## Datas não têm formato

Uma data é apenas um conceito, uma ideia: ela representa um ponto específico no calendário.

A data de "1 de janeiro de 1970" representa isso: o ponto específico do calendário que corresponde ao dia 1 do mês de janeiro do ano de 1970.
Para expressar essa ideia em forma de texto, eu posso escrevê-la de diferentes formas:

- 01/01/1970 (um formato bem comum em muitos países, incluindo o Brasil)
- 1/1/1970 (formato americano, invertendo o dia e mês)
- 1970-01-01 (o formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601))
- Primeiro de Janeiro de 1970 (em bom português)
- January 1<sup>st</sup>, 1970 (em inglês)
- 1970年1月1日 (em japonês)
- e muitos outros...

Repare que cada um dos formatos acima é diferente, mas **todos representam a mesma data** (os mesmos valores numéricos do dia, mês e ano).

---

Dito isso, se você menciona que tem "datas em formatos diferentes", provavelmente o que você tem são `Strings` contendo representações de uma data em formatos diferentes (ou você imprimiu a data e método que a exibe está usando algum formato específico). Pode parecer meio pedante, mas esta distinção é importante, pois uma `String` é uma coisa, um `java.util.Date` é outra (o primeiro é um texto que *pode* representar uma data, o segundo representa o conceito de um ponto na linha do tempo, sem qualquer noção de formato).

Se você não sabe em qual formato está a `String`, o melhor que pode fazer é tentar um a um, até encontrar um que funcione:

```
String s = "10/04/2019";
// formatos possíveis
SimpleDateFormat[] formatos = {
    new SimpleDateFormat("dd 'de' MMM 'de' yyyy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
};
Date data = null; // java.util.Date
for (SimpleDateFormat sdf : formatos) {
    try {
        data = sdf.parse(s);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("String está no formato inválido, tentar o próximo");
    }
}
if (data != null) {
    System.out.println(data);
} else {
    System.out.println("Não foi possível obter a data");
}
```

Se quiser, pode chamar `sdf.setLenient(true);` antes do `parse`, para garantir que somente datas válidas sejam aceitas (por default, `SimpleDateFormat` aceita valores como 32 de janeiro, que é automaticamente ajustado para 1 de fevereiro, além de [fazer algumas coisas bem estranhas](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue172.html), dependendo da situação - usar `setLenient(true)` cancela este comportamento e só aceita datas válidas).

Se o nome do mês está sempre em português, recomendo usar um `java.util.Locale` no construtor de `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd 'de' MMM 'de' yyyy", new Locale("pt", "BR"))
```

Se você não especifica um `Locale`, ele usa o *default* da JVM, e nem sempre é garantido que seja português. Se você tem certeza que o nome do mês sempre está em português, melhor usar o `Locale` correspondente.

Isso tudo é para transformar uma `String` em um `java.util.Date`. Agora se quiser mostrar a data em um formato específico, você deve usar um `SimpleDateFormat` próprio, contendo o formato desejado:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatoSaida = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(formatoSaida.format(data));
```

O método `format` recebe um `Date` e retorna uma `String`, contendo a data no formato indicado.

---

## `java.time`

A partir da API Level 26 (necessário minSdkVersion>=26, não basta ter compileSdkVersion>=26), é possível usar a API [`java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary), muito melhor e mais moderna que `Date` e `SimpleDateFormat`.

Um recurso adicionado nesta API são os padrões opcionais, o que possibilita o *parsing* de mais de um formato:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.LocalDate;

String s = "10 de abr de 2019";
// formatos possíveis
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[dd/MM/uuuu][dd 'de' MMM 'de' uuuu]", new Locale("pt", "BR"));
LocalDate data = LocalDate.parse(s, parser); // obter a data
// formato de saída
DateTimeFormatter formatoSaida = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
System.out.println(formatoSaida.format(data)); // 10/04/2019
```

No exemplo acima, cada formato está entre colchetes, indicando que são opcionais. Então o `parse` funciona com ambos os formatos, e repare que também uso um `Locale` correspondente ao idioma português por causa do nome do mês. E também uso outro `DateTimeFormatter` específico para o formato de saída.

Outro detalhe é que nesta API há várias classes diferentes para representar datas. No exemplo acima eu usei `LocalDate`, que é uma classe que só possui dia, mês e ano (pois é o que a `String` possui).

Se quiser trabalhar com datas e horários, você terá que usar um `LocalDateTime` (mas terá que setar algum horário nela, já que a `String` não possui esta informação). Para trabalhar com datas e horas em um fuso horário específico, existe a classe `ZonedDateTime`. Para mais detalhes, você pode consultar o [tutorial da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) e [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052).

---

Para API Level < 26, uma alternativa é o [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), um excelente *backport* do `java.time`, que possui a maioria das classes, métodos e funcionalidades. A diferença é que em vez de estarem no pacote `java.time`, as classes ficam no pacote `org.threeten.bp`. Para usá-lo no Android, siga as instruções [deste link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754) (e [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/370367/112052) há mais algumas diferenças entre o *backport* e o `java.time`, na seção "Alternativas para Java < 8").

---

## Não use regex

Apesar de *parecer* uma boa ideia, usar regex para verificar se uma data é válida [não é a melhor solução](https://hkotsubo.github.io/blog/2019-04-05/posso-usar-regex-para-validar-datas) (também falo um pouco sobre isso [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/363711/112052)). Basta ver a regex que você colocou na pergunta: você consegue entender quais pontos correspondem ao dia, ano e mês? Consegue mudá-la para aceitar os nomes dos meses? Além disso, ela está usando `\D` como separador (ou seja, qualquer caractere que não seja um dígito), então ela aceita strings como `30a01a2019` (a letra `a` não é um dígito - ou seja, corresponde a `\D` - então a regex aceita-a como separador dos campos de data - [veja aqui outros exemplos](https://regex101.com/r/Vp5tjJ/2/)).

Outro ponto é que validação de datas envolve operações e comparações numéricas: verificar se o dia é maior que 31 (ou 30, ou 28/29, dependendo do mês), verificar se o ano é múltiplo de 4, ou múltiplo de 400 caso também seja múltiplo de 100 (para saber se é bissexto e se devo considerar 28 ou 29 dias para fevereiro), etc.

Só que regex trabalha com texto, e mesmo os dígitos são tratados como caracteres, por isso ela não consegue fazer operações aritméticas. Em vez disso, a regex tem que usar [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), com várias possibilidades: dia 31 com meses 1, 3, 5, etc..., ou dia 30 para meses 4, 6, etc... ou 29 de fevereiro para anos x, y, z (existem alguns "truques" para deixar a verificação de anos bissextos menos longa), e por aí vai. Por isso a regex fica tão grande, mas sinceramente, não vale a pena usá-la, ainda mais quando a API nativa já possui classes específicas para lidar com o problema.

Se surgir um formato novo, por exemplo, basta acrescentá-lo no array de `SimpleDateFormat` acima. Mas imagine o trabalho para mudar a regex...

---

#### SQLite

Baseado no [seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/379491/como-tratar-diferentes-formatos-de-data/379528#comment752064_379491), fiz um teste no SQLite (que confesso não usar com frequência). Usei a versão 3.28 nos meus testes.

Geralmente os bancos de dados possuem tipos específicos para datas e horas, e tudo que você precisa fazer é salvar o `Date` e pronto (sem se importar com o formato usado, pois como já foi dito, datas não têm formato).

Mas segundo a [documentação do SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), ele não possui tipos específicos para lidar com datas. Em vez disso, você pode escolher armazená-las como texto (usando o formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)), ou como um número, contendo o valor do [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052).

No seu caso, como você parece estar interessado apenas no dia, mês e ano, eu sugiro usar um campo texto no formato ISO 8601. Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
// manipule a data conforme o que você precisar
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5);
// grave-a no banco no formato ISO 8601
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String textoQueVaiSerSalvoNoBanco = sdf.format(cal.getTime());

// se estiver usando PreparedStatement
ps.setString(1, textoQueVaiSerSalvoNoBanco);
```

Então você salva no banco como uma `String`. Ela ficará no formato ISO 8601 (ano-mês-dia). Para recuperá-la, basta obter a `String` e fazer o *parsing*:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
// rs é um ResultSet (caso seja o que você está usando)
Date date = sdf.parse(rs.getString("data_texto"));
```

Uma vez tendo o `Date`, você pode fazer o que quiser com ele. Pode setá-lo em um `Calendar` para manipulá-lo:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(date); // setar o Date
// manipular a data conforme necessário
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2);
```

Ou ainda mostrá-la em outro formato:

```
// mostrar o Date em outro formato
SimpleDateFormat formatoSaida = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(formatoSaida.format(date));
```

---

O mesmo vale para o `java.time` (caso você esteja usando API Level >= 26). Para manipular a data, use um `LocalDate`:

```
// data atual mais 5 dias
LocalDate data = LocalDate.now().plusDays(5);
ps.setString(1, date.toString());
```

A vantagem de `LocalDate` é que seu método `toString()` já retorna a data no formato ISO 8601. Além disso, esta classe também consegue fazer *parsing* de uma `String` nesse formato diretamente, então obter o texto do banco e transformá-lo em data também é fácil:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(rs.getString("data_texto"));
```

Para mostrar esta data em outro formato, aí você precisa de um `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
// mostrar o LocalDate em outro formato
DateTimeFormatter formatoSaida = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
System.out.println(formatoSaida.format(date));
```

Comment: Vendo a sua edição, parece que a [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/379798/2541) lhe foi útil :)

Comment: @ramaral Agora percebi que esqueci de votar na sua resposta! Obrigado :-)

Comment: Para tornar mais claro: para usar o `java.time` é necessário  `minSdkVersion >= 26`, não basta ter `compileSdkVersion >= 26`, ou seja, um programa que use `java.time` só corre em dispositivos Android 8 ou superior

Comment: @ramaral Desse detalhe eu não sabia. Atualizei a resposta, obrigado mais uma vez! :-)

Comment: Vejo que se meu código ficar depreciado, terei condições de resolver recorrendo as  dicas.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é viável para o seu projeto alterar o tipo de dados da data mas vou explicar como trabalho com datas e não tenho esses problemas que você está tendo.

Sempre quando trabalho com data prefiro utilizar epoch timestamp principalmente por dois motivos:

- Quando vou salvar no banco ele é so um inteiro, deste momento é 1556271003, isso facilita na
  interoperabilidade entre diferentes fornecedores de bancos de dados
- Se eu quiser somar X tempo em uma data é só somar os segundos, ou
  milisegundos, no inteiro que representa a data

Então no seu caso eu faria o seguinte, salva e trabalha sempre com a data sendo um timestamp e quando vai mostrar para o usuário você formata como deseja a saída. Exemplo:

```
long unixSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
Date date = new java.util.Date(unixSeconds); 
// o formato que você quer a saida
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"); 
// seta o timezone
sdf.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4")); 
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Código adaptado de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17433005/6009128

Comment: Somar X tempo nem sempre é tão trivial com `java.util.Date`, pois há várias "pegadinhas" se for somar [dias](https://hkotsubo.github.io/blog/2019-04-06/nao-reinvente-a-roda-como-somar-dias-a-uma-data), e principalmente [meses e anos](https://hkotsubo.github.io/blog/2019-04-09/nao-reinvente-a-roda-2-como-somar-meses-e-anos-a-uma-data) - nesses casos, é melhor usar `java.util.Calendar` (ou a API [`java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary), caso esteja disponível) :-)

Comment: sim, tem algumas coisas que tem que tomar cuidado mesmo, mas se eu sempre trabalhar com o epoch e ir somando ou diminuindo os segundos não tem problemas, correto?

Comment: Depende do que quer fazer. Se for somar horas, minutos ou segundos, não tem muito problema. Se for somar dias, meses ou anos, surgem as situações citadas nos links que passei, então apenas somar ao valor do timestamp não é suficiente

Comment: no meu caso gostaria de obter um mesmo padrão de data independente do dispositivo.
eu teria que editar a data com "new Locale("pt", "BR")" antes de gravar no banco de dados? 
Somente a API java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter pode fazer isso?
.ofPattern("[dd/MM/uuuu][dd 'de' MMM 'de' uuuu]"
Algum meio de fazer sem precisar alterar a API?

Comment: O problema está em somente recebem uma data padronizada, apenas para complementar o entendimento, se assim facilita: [Empréstimo]obtenho uma dataAtual e somo 5 dias a uma dataDevolucao, após isso, [Renovação] recebo dataDevolucao e adiciono mais 1 dia obtendo DataRenovacao.