# Inserir um DateTime em uma tag input do tipo date

Tags: javascript, html, data

Estou tentando inserir a data atual em uma tag `input` do tipo `datetime-local`.

Tag Input:

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="inputDateNow" class="registerInput inputCodeDate" placeholder="Activation" readonly>
```

Método JavaScript que recupera a data atual:

```
function getDateNow() {
    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
    var time = today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes();
    var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;
    var todayDate = new Date(dateTime);

    return todayDate;
}
```

Atribuição:

```
inputDateNow.value = getDateNow();
```

Error:

> The specified value "Invalid Date" does not conform to the required
>   format.  The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss"
>   or ":ss.SSS".

Não estou achando onde esta o erro, já que estou passando a data no formato  `YYYY-MM-DD`. Gostaria que alguém pudesse me ajudar apontando onde estou errando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#Value), o valor de um campo `datetime-local` [deve ser uma string contendo a data e hora](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats#Local_date_and_time_strings) no formato "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sss" (sendo que os segundos e frações de segundo são opcionais).

Ou seja, o mês, dia, hora e minuto devem estar escritos com dois dígitos (e com um zero à esquerda, caso seja menor que 10), e entre a data e hora deve ter a letra "T" (este formato é definido pela [norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)).

Sendo assim, basta fazer:

```js
function getDateNow() {
    let today = new Date();
    let date = today.getFullYear() + '-' +
        (today.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0') + '-' +
        today.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    let time = today.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + today.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    return date + 'T' + time;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    document.getElementById('inputDateNow').value = getDateNow();
});
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="inputDateNow" readonly>
```

No caso, eu uso [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) para converter os números para string, e [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) para preencher com zeros à esquerda, caso necessário.

---

No seu caso, você estava retornando um [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), mas conforme já dito, o valor deve ser uma string. Foi feita uma confusão relativamente comum: conforme eu já disse [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/364683/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/368075/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/367704/112052), **datas não têm formato**.

Uma data é apenas um conceito, uma ideia: ela representa um ponto específico no calendário.

A data de "1 de janeiro de 1970", por exemplo, representa isso: o ponto específico do calendário que corresponde ao dia 1 do mês de janeiro do ano de 1970. Para expressar essa ideia em forma de texto, eu posso escrevê-la de diferentes formas:

- 01/01/1970 (um formato bem comum em muitos países, incluindo o Brasil)
- 1/1/1970 (formato americano, invertendo o dia e mês)
- 1970-01-01 (o formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601))
- Primeiro de Janeiro de 1970 (em bom português)
- January 1st, 1970 (em inglês)
- 1970年1月1日 (em japonês)
- e muitos outros...

Repare que cada um dos formatos acima é diferente, mas **todos representam a mesma data** (os mesmos valores numéricos do dia, mês e ano).

Dito isso, o [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) do JavaScript representa o conceito de uma data (um ponto na linha do tempo), mas ela em si não tem um formato. Strings, por sua vez, podem representar uma data em um formato específico. E o `value` de um `input type="datetime-local"` recebe uma string contendo a data em um formato específico.