# Converter uma str em datetime no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, data

Estou criando um gerenciador de tarefas que deve receber uma tarefa com uma data limite. Esse gerenciador vai verificar quantos dias faltam para o prazo e avisar quando chegar. Porém, estou tendo um problema na hora de converter o `input` de data em `str` para `datetime`.

Estou usando Python 3 no Pycharm.

```
from datetime import datetime

data_hoje = hoje.strftime('%d/%m/%y')  # Descobrindo a data atual para 
posteriormente comparar com a data limite

input_data_limite = input('DATA LIMITE: ') # Entrando com a data limite 

data_limite = datetime.strftime(input_data_limite, '%d/%m/%y') # deveria 
converter em datetime mas da erro

print(data_limite)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) converte uma data (um [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects)) para uma string (que é o contrário do que você quer fazer).

No caso, você tem o retorno de [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), que é uma string (e não uma data), e está passando-a para `strftime`, por isso dá erro.

Se quer converter uma string para uma data, use [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) (repare no "p" em vez do "f"). Ex:

```
from datetime import date, datetime

hoje = date.today()
input_data_limite = input('DATA LIMITE: ')
data_limite = datetime.strptime(input_data_limite, '%d/%m/%y')

diferenca = data_limite.date() - hoje
print(diferenca.days) # diferença em dias
```

Repare que usei [`date()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) para converter o `datetime` para [`date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects), pois pelo que entendi, você só quer levar em conta a data (dia, mês e ano), sem considerar o horário.

Por fim, eu calculo a diferença entre as datas, e o resultado é um [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), do qual é possível extrair a quantidade de dias correspondente.

---

Um detalhe importante é que o formato `%y` (com "y" minúsculo), aceita o ano com 2 dígitos. Se quiser aceitar o formato "dd/mm/yyyy" (ano com 4 dígitos), use `%Y` - com "Y" maiúsculo.

Outro detalhe é que `strptime` lança um [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) se a string estiver em um formato que não corresponde ao informado. Neste caso, você poderia fazer um *loop* para que o usuário digite novamente a data, até que ela esteja no formato válido:

```
while True:
    try:
        input_data_limite = input('DATA LIMITE: ')
        data_limite = datetime.strptime(input_data_limite, '%d/%m/%y')
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Data em formato inválido, tente novamente')
```

---

#### Sobre datas e formatos

Apenas para complementar, conforme eu já disse [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/364683/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/368075/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/367704/112052), **datas não têm formato**.

Uma data é apenas um conceito, uma ideia: ela representa um ponto específico no calendário.

A data de "2 de janeiro de 1970", por exemplo, representa isso: o ponto específico do calendário que corresponde ao dia 2 do mês de janeiro do ano de 1970. Para expressar essa ideia em forma de texto, eu posso escrevê-la de diferentes formas:

- 02/01/1970 (um formato bem comum em muitos países, incluindo o Brasil)
- 1/2/1970 (formato americano, invertendo o dia e mês)
- 1970-01-02 (o [formato ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601))
- Dois de Janeiro de 1970 (em bom português)
- January 2<sup>nd</sup>, 1970 (em inglês)
- 1970年1月2日 (em japonês)
- e muitos outros...

Repare que cada um dos formatos acima é diferente, mas **todos representam a mesma data** (os mesmos valores numéricos do dia, mês e ano).

Sendo assim, um `datetime` representa uma data (um ponto na linha do tempo), mas ele por si só não possui um formato. Já uma string pode conter um texto que representa uma data em um formato específico.

Quando você quer transformar uma string (como por exemplo "20/10/2019") em uma data, está fazendo um *parsing* (que é o "p" do método `strptime`). Já quando quer representar uma data em um formato específico (ou seja, transformá-la em uma string), está fazendo uma formatação (o "f" do método `strftime`). O seu erro foi tentar fazer uma formatação quando na verdade queria fazer um *parsing*.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Ajudou demais no que eu estou tentando fazer. 
Realmente, estou querendo somente comparar as datas, não levando em conta o horario.

Comment: Quando você quer transformar uma string (como por exemplo "20/10/2019") em uma data, está fazendo um parsing (que é o "p" do método strptime). Já quando quer representar uma data em um formato específico (ou seja, transformá-la em uma string), está fazendo uma formatação (o "f" do método strftime). O seu erro foi tentar fazer uma formatação quando na verdade queria fazer um parsing.

Essa questão foi realmente muito boa para entender melhor o que fazer. Obrigado, novamente

Comment: É a primeira vez que uso o stackoverflow. Ainda não estou muito familiarizado com as mecanicas. Mas vou aprendendo kkk Obrigado, mais uma vez!

Comment: @JuninhoSouza Sem problemas, eu tb demorei um pouco pra entender como o site funciona, mas com o tempo a gente pega o jeito :-)