# Contagem de data de dias quando tem virada de ano

Tags: python, python-3.x, data, datetime

Estou tendo problemas em gerar uma iteração onde é exibido as datas de um determinado dia até o dia mais atual.
esse problema acontece quando tem a "virada do ano" e se coloco uma condição de "parada".

Código com retorno errado:

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame({"datasolicitada":['21/12/2020 00:00','18/12/2020 00:00']})

data = df0['datasolicitada'].max()
data1 = datetime.strptime(data, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
data2 = data1.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
datahj = datetime.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

for i in range(30):
    dia = (data1 + timedelta(days=i)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    if datahj > dia:
        print (dia)
```

Se eu executo somente o `print` da contagem, me é retornado até a soma conforme a `range`

```
for i in range(30):
    dia = (data1 + timedelta(days=i)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    print (dia)
```

Resultados:

```
    if datahj > dia:
        print (dia)
01/01/2021
02/01/2021
03/01/2021
04/01/2021
05/01/2021
```

se troco o sinal da condição:

```
    if datahj < dia:
        print (dia)
21/12/2020
22/12/2020
23/12/2020
24/12/2020
25/12/2020
26/12/2020
27/12/2020
28/12/2020
29/12/2020
30/12/2020
31/12/2020
07/01/2021
08/01/2021
09/01/2021
10/01/2021
11/01/2021
12/01/2021
13/01/2021
14/01/2021
15/01/2021
16/01/2021
17/01/2021
18/01/2021
19/01/2021
```

resultado que gostaria de ter:

```
21/12/2020
22/12/2020
23/12/2020
24/12/2020
25/12/2020
26/12/2020
27/12/2020
28/12/2020
29/12/2020
30/12/2020
31/12/2020
01/01/2021
02/01/2021
03/01/2021
04/01/2021
05/01/2021
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) retorna uma string contendo a representação da data, e não a data em si.

Se quer comparar somente a data, sem levar em conta o horário, você pode converter tudo para [`date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects), em vez de usar [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

dt_inicio = datetime.strptime('21/12/2020 00:00', "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M").date()
hoje = date.today()
dt = dt_inicio
while dt < hoje:
    print(dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
    dt += timedelta(days=1)
```

Repare que eu só uso `strftime` na hora de imprimir a data. Mas na hora de comparar com a data atual eu uso os próprios objetos `date` (usei [`date.today()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today) em vez de `datetime.today()`, pois pelo que entendi você não quer levar em conta o horário).

E no *loop* eu vou somando 1 dia até que a data seja igual ao dia de hoje.

---

Mas se a ideia é avançar no máximo 30 dias ou até a data atual (o que ocorrer primeiro), ficaria assim:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
 
dt_inicio = datetime.strptime('21/12/2020 00:00', "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M").date()
hoje = date.today()
for i in range(30):
    dt = dt_inicio + timedelta(days=i)
    if dt < hoje:
        print(dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
    else: break # encerra o for
```

Ou seja, só imprimo a data se for anterior à data atual, e caso contrário eu já encerro o *loop*.

---

E só para esclarecer a confusão que você fez...

## Datas não têm formato

Conforme eu já disse [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/364683/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/368075/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/367704/112052), **datas não têm formato**.

Uma data é apenas um conceito, uma ideia: ela representa um ponto específico no calendário.

A data de "1 de janeiro de 1970", por exemplo, representa isso: o ponto específico do calendário que corresponde ao dia 1 do mês de janeiro do ano de 1970. Para expressar essa ideia em forma de texto, eu posso escrevê-la de diferentes formas:

- 01/01/1970 (um formato bem comum em muitos países, incluindo o Brasil)
- 1/1/1970 (formato americano, invertendo o dia e mês)
- 1970-01-01 (o formato [ISO 8601](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects))
- Primeiro de Janeiro de 1970 (em bom português)
- January 1st, 1970 (em inglês)
- 1970年1月1日 (em japonês)
- e muitos outros...

Repare que cada um dos formatos acima é diferente, mas **todos representam a mesma data** (os mesmos valores numéricos do dia, mês e ano).

No caso do Python, um objeto `datetime` ou `date` representa uma data (estes objetos não possuem formato, somente valores que representam a data).

Quando você usa `strftime` está retornando uma string (uma representação da data em determinado formato). Mas uma string não é uma data: strings são comparadas [lexicograficamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/440496/112052), então mesmo dígitos (como `0`, `1`, etc) são tratados como caracteres. Já datas são comparadas levando em conta os valores (ano, mês, dia, etc), por isso que comparar datas não é o mesmo que comparar strings (mesmo que as strings representem as datas).

Comment: muito obrigado pela explicação, vou ler mais sobre, abraço