# Como validar se uma data é maior que a outra considerando dia, mês e ano

Tags: javascript, data, momentjs

Preciso validar se a "Data Atual" é maior que a "Data de Vencimento", mas parece que o Moment.js compara apenas os dias e não leva em consideração mês/ano.

```
var dataAtual = moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY');//12/01/2021
var dataVencimento = moment(item.dataVencimento).format('DD/MM/YYYY');

console.log(moment(dataAtual).isAfter(dataVencimento)) //true
```

12/01/2021 (Data de Hoje) não é maior que 01/02/2021. O resultado deveria ser `false`, mas ele comparou apenas o dia, pois dia 12 é maior que dia 01 e retornou `true`. Está errado!

Estou trabalhando com datas de vencimento mensais e o retorno deveria ser conforme informei de vermelho na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma maneira de fazer com que ele considere dia/mês/ano e valide as datas corretamente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que [`format`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) retorna uma string, e strings são comparadas lexicograficamente, ou seja, mesmo dígitos como `0` e `1` são tratados como caracteres, e por isso uma string que começa com `0` é considerada "menor" do que uma que começa com `1` (você pode [ler aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/440496/112052) para entender melhor este comportamento).

No caso do Moment.js, `isAfter` aceita strings como parâmetro, e ele tenta fazer o *parsing*, mas como você passou uma string no formato "dd/mm/yyyy" e não é garantido que este será reconhecido, ele não consegue fazer a comparação corretamente (da [documentação](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/): "*Browser support for parsing strings is inconsistent. Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers*").

<sub>Obs: no meu teste, deu erro em vez de retornar `true`, mas enfim, de qualquer forma não deve ser feito desta maneira.</sub>

Se quer comparar datas, não transforme-as em string. No caso, use os próprios objetos `moment`:

```js
var dataAtual = moment(); // data atual
var dataVencimento = moment('2021-02-01');

console.log(dataAtual.isAfter(dataVencimento, 'day')); // false
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

No caso, usei `'day'` como segundo parâmetro para que ele não leve em conta o horário (veja a [documentação](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/)), pois entendi que você só comparar o dia, mês e ano, independente do horário. Isso é necessário porque a data/hora atual também terá o horário e sem o segundo parâmetro, este também é levado em conta na comparação.

---

Só para constar, o seu erro foi confundir datas com formatos. Mas entenda uma coisa: conforme eu já disse [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/364683/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/368075/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/367704/112052), **datas não têm formato**.

Uma data é apenas um conceito, uma ideia: ela representa um ponto específico no calendário.

A data de "1 de janeiro de 1970", por exemplo, representa isso: o ponto específico do calendário que corresponde ao dia 1 do mês de janeiro do ano de 1970. Para expressar essa ideia em forma de texto, eu posso escrevê-la de diferentes formas:

- 01/01/1970 (um formato bem comum em muitos países, incluindo o Brasil)
- 1/1/1970 (formato americano, invertendo o dia e mês)
- 1970-01-01 (o formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601))
- Primeiro de Janeiro de 1970 (em bom português)
- January 1st, 1970 (em inglês)
- 1970年1月1日 (em japonês)
- e muitos outros...

Repare que cada um dos formatos acima é diferente, mas **todos representam a mesma data** (os mesmos valores numéricos do dia, mês e ano).

No caso, um objeto `moment` representa uma data, e `format` retorna uma string que representa esta data em algum formato.

Se quer comparar datas, não use strings, use as próprias datas.

---

Mas só por curiosidade, um formato que permite uma comparação direta sem esses problemas é o definido pela [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

```js
var dataAtual = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // data atual
var dataVencimento = moment('2021-02-01').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

console.log(dataAtual > dataVencimento); // false
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Mas claro que, se você já tem as datas, não faz sentido transformá-las em strings para compará-las, sendo que as próprias datas já podem ser comparadas diretamente.

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente resposta @hkotsubo! Ficou muito claro agora! Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Uma possibilidade, sem usar bibliotecas externas, é fazer isto:

```
// obter a data de hoje no formato yyyy-mm-dd
let hoje = new Date(2021, 1 - 1, 12); // para 12/01/2021
let hojeYMD = (new Date(hoje.getTime() -
    (hoje.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000))).toISOString().split('T')[0];

// obter a data de vencimento no formato yyyy-mm-dd 
let dataVencimento = "01/02/2021"
let trechos = dataVencimento.split("/");
let dataVencimentoYMD = [trechos[2], trechos[1], trechos[0]].join("-")

// comparar as duas datas que estão como string e no mesmo formato
let vencido = hojeYMD > dataVencimentoYMD;
console.log(vencido);
```

Como funciona:

- `let hoje = new Date(2021, 1 - 1, 12)` é para definir a data de hoje do seu exemplo;
- `let hojeYMD = new Date(hoje.getTime() - (hoje.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000))` converte a data do fuso horário atual para o UTC (fuso horário 0 - GMT - Greenwich), `.toISOString()` converte a data para o formato yyyy-mm-ddThh:nn:ss.zzzZ e `.split('T')[0]` separa a data da hora e pega somente a data;
- `let dataVencimento = "01/02/2021"` é a data da sua tabela;
- `let trechos = dataVencimento.split("/")` separa o dia, mês e ano da data de vencimento;
- `let dataVencimentoYMD = [trechos[2], trechos[1], trechos[0]].join("-")` recria a string da data de vencimento no formato yyyy-mm-dd;
- `let vencido = hojeYMD > dataVencimentoYMD` compara as duas variáveis string que estão no formato yyyy-mm-dd;
- `console.log(vencido)` imprime no Console o valor booleano (true ou false) que indica se a data de vencimento é anterior à data de hoje.

---

### Demo

```js
// obter a data de hoje no formato yyyy-mm-dd
let hoje = new Date(2021, 1 - 1, 12); // para 12/01/2021
let hojeYMD = (new Date(hoje.getTime() -
    (hoje.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000))).toISOString().split('T')[0];

// obter a data de vencimento no formato yyyy-mm-dd 
let dataVencimento = "01/02/2021"
let trechos = dataVencimento.split("/");
let dataVencimentoYMD = [trechos[2], trechos[1], trechos[0]].join("-")

// comparar as duas datas que estão como string e no mesmo formato
let vencido = hojeYMD > dataVencimentoYMD;
console.log(vencido);
```

Comment: Somar ou subtrair um valor ao `getTime` não é uma boa (pode até "funcionar", mas na verdade vc está criando uma data referente a um instante diferente, e não "convertendo o timezone"). Isso porque o `Date` do JavaScript na verdade representa um [timestamp](/q/70473/112052) (um ponto na linha do tempo), e não possui um timezone atrelado. Para mais detalhes, leia [aqui](/q/456089/112052), [aqui](/q/455437/112052) e [aqui](/a/344030/112052). Outro detalhe é que `toISOString` já retorna a data convertida para UTC, então não precisava usar `getTimezoneOffset`, bastaria fazer `hoje.toISOString()`

Comment: Compreendi. Muito obrigado pela sua contribuição. O que você acha de usar este código para gerar o hojeYMD?
```let hoje = new Date(); /* ou new Date(2021, 1 - 1, 12); */

let hojeYMD = [hoje.getFullYear(), (hoje.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0'), hoje.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')].join('-');```

Comment: Continuando o comentário anterior: Eu, por exemplo, estou no fuso horário de Brasília (GMT-0300). Se agora fossem 22h, o ```hoje.toISOString()``` iria retornar a data de amanhã.

Comment: Sim, vai ter vários corner cases desse tipo, por isso o melhor é comparar os objetos  `Date` diretamente, sem transformar em string